# Is using a power bank at higher intensity risky?

Tags: power-supply, cable, adapter, power-bank, power-converter

I have a Packard Bell ZG5 with a 19V, 1.58A (30W) charger. I'd like to be able to connect it to some power bank to increase the battery life (spare parts are very expensive), so I have found [this barrel adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W8TRS5Q) which would allow me to do so with [that power bank](https://www.boulanger.com/ref/8008232). The thing is, it outputs 3A instead of 1.58, which would make it almost 60W (it's described as 45W, so I'd like some explanations here).

So I'm wondering if it's likely to fry my computer or is it okay, or how can I find that out ? What solution would you suggest me instead ?

Comment: What battery life are you trying to extend ?  I am struggling to see this is going to do anything.  Most laptops run from the battery, even when plugged in to the mains.  The test is that the laptop will not run connected to the mains, without a battery in it.

Comment: Amps are 'pulled' by the device, not 'pushed' by the power source, so this is perfectly safe. [This has been covered many, many times on Super User & elsewhere.]